# Examine does not index several sites

Tags: indexing, umbraco, lucene.net, examine

We have multiple sites in a Umbraco directory.

Sites are mainly cloned in English or French.

That sites search is managed by the Examine engine.
The indexes are located respectively in IndexEN and IndexFR folders.

After analyzing the indexes in the IndexFR folders I observed that mainly all sites are indexed, but there are some sites that are not (respectively, the search result is always empty).

Why? What could be the main causes that a Umbraco node (that corresponds to a site) is not indexed by the Examine engine?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question within the scope defined in the [help]

Comment: Indexing a umbraco ASP.NET site with the examine (Lucene.net) engine is not a programming question?

Comment: @MikeW : read carrefully the help center:  "*if your question generally covers…
software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!*"

Comment: Explain to me, then, how I might help diagnose a problem with your code based on the information you have provided. You've given no code, no sample data, no error messages. Your entire question can be summed up as 'Some of my sites aren't indexed. Why?'. At best you might get a speculative answer. I'd expect someone who's been a member for nearly five years to produce a better question than this. If you think my assessment is wrong, ask for a second opinion on [meta]

Comment: I don't know the cause of the problem. Usualy people that faced that kind of problems know WHAT to ASK the PO (even a question can be an answer). I am ready to give more details, but I don't know what details could I give. So please if you don't know the subject, don't dowgrade the question giving as reference the help center scopes that you never read apparently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the Examine indexes, then restarted the site (indexes was recreated by Examine), also cloned the existing "My Site FR" node into a new identical one that I published instead of the existing one.

As result, Examine indexed the new node and I could see some search results on the site...